# Showing a short date according to users localId

Tags: c#, cultureinfo

I need to present a short date 30-01 (30th Jan) according to the users LocaleId. The date must be displayed correctly according to the users local. Examples of expected possible permutations of the date format are: 30-01, 01-30, 30/01, 01/30, etc ..

Note 1: I don't want the year to appear in the date string.
Note 2: You can assume we already know the LocalId.
Note 3: MyDate.ToString("dd/MM") is not the answer I'm looking for as it's not considering the local.

Comment: _"MyDate.ToString("dd/MM") is not the answer I'm looking for as it's not considering the local"_ **it does** considering the local date separator since [`/` is a custom format specifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.100%29.aspx#dateSeparator).

Comment: Lets assume the user's local displays a date as dd-MM or MM-dd? All the non custom date/string formats include the year. Perhaps the only answer is to remove the year manually.

Comment: Is this a Desktop app, or a web application? If it's something where it is installed on the user's machine, that will be much easier.

Comment: Look at the standard format strings for DateTime, also take a look at the underlying Windows API. In case if there's no format you need - then lo luck, Windows just doesn't have it. Then you have two options 1) try cut the year part from the other date format, or 2) "reinvent" formatting yourself, based on ssome ISO standard governing it.

Comment: @krillgar this is a REST web app, the processing is done server side, nothing is installed on the users machine - but I did mention you can assume we know users the localId.

Comment: @Sergey thanks - option one is probably the easiest, since there is no standard for format for just ddMM.

Answer (score 2):

*"MyDate.ToString("dd/MM") is not the answer I'm looking for as it's not considering the local"*

Actually **it does** considering the local date separator since [`/` is a custom format specifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.100%29.aspx#dateSeparator).

```
DateTime dt = new DateTime(2014, 01, 30);
string result = dt.ToString("dd/MM"); // 30.01. for example in germany
```

But since you want the correct *order* (month /  day or vice-versa), this is the best that comes to my mind:

```
DateTime dt = new DateTime(2014, 01, 30);
var dfi = DateTimeFormatInfo.CurrentInfo;
var patternWithoutYear = dfi.ShortDatePattern
    .Split(new[]{ dfi.DateSeparator }, StringSplitOptions.None)
    .Where(token => !token.Contains("yy"));
string result = dt.ToString(string.Join(dfi.DateSeparator, patternWithoutYear));
```